# php monitoring to improve performance

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, nginx

I made a little raw php script just to test performance querying my database.

This just build a single looping in all documents of all collections.

```
 <?php

    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://user:pass@serer:27017/db");
    $db = $m->dbname;

    $users       = $db->users->find();        <=== 300k docs, 1 index
    $machines    = $db->machines->find();     <=== 350k docs, 1 index
    $chars       = $db->characters->find();   <=== 10k  docs, 2 indexes
    $stats    = $db->stats->find();        <=== 10k  docs, 1 index

    $allinfos = array();

    foreach ($users as $k => $v) {  array_push($allinfos, array('item'=>1)); }
    foreach ($machines as $k => $v){ array_push($allinfos, array('item'=>1)); }
    foreach ($chars as $k => $v) {  array_push($allinfos, array('item'=>1)); }
    foreach ($stats as $k => $v) {  array_push($allinfos, array('item'=>1)); }

    print count($allinfos);

 ?>
```

In my local Apache the script took 2 minutes to finish processing, but works.

**During the process:**

- Database server RAM max comsuption: **7%**. (the server has 8GB RAM with 80gb SSD)
- Database server CPU max comsuption: **3%**.
- Localhost HTTPD process RAM max comsuption: **70mb**.

**Tweaks I made:** Changed in php.ini the memory_limit to **1048M**.

--

1. How can I tune up performance?
2. Why this don't use more CPU and RAM to process faster?
3. Change apache to nginx?

Comment: This looks like the kind of script that would not be run in a web context anyway - you wouldn't want to display all 670K rows, so can you try running it on the console? That takes any web server out of the equation.

Comment: This is a good point, thanks. It worked in my local Terminal and after 2 minutes printed final value. This is the same time than running in Apache. Maybe the bottleneck is in the database?

Comment: What are you trying to do with your queries? It's going to be heavily IO bound as it tries to retrieve every single document in 4 collections? I wouldn't expect this to be fast. (It seems more like "worst case scenario") Does this represent an actual query that you want to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is such a broad question that it is hard to know where to begin aside from asking where is your bottleneck? You can profile your script like this:

```
<?php

    $start = microtime(true);
    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://user:pass@serer:27017/db");
    $db = $m->dbname;
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).' : Connected to server<br><br>';

    $start = microtime(true);
    $users       = $db->users->find();        // <=== 300k docs, 1 index
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).' : Users query ('.count($users).')<br><br>';

    $start = microtime(true);
    $machines    = $db->machines->find();     // <=== 350k docs, 1 index
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).' : Machines query ('.count($machines).')<br><br>';

    $start = microtime(true);
    $chars       = $db->characters->find();   // <=== 10k  docs, 2 indexes
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).' : Chars query ('.count($chars).')<br><br>';

    $start = microtime(true);
    $stats    = $db->stats->find();           // <=== 10k  docs, 1 index
    echo (microtime(true) - $start).' : Stats query ('.count($stats).')<br><br>';

?>
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. running this in local terminal, it shows less than 3ms for ALL QUERIES. the slowness is looping on 300k arrays. More than 1 minute.

Comment: so the problem is not in database. all right? the problem is in PHP machine?

Comment: Well what is your purpose for looping all those records and doing an `array_push()`?

Comment: just simulating processes I will do in my apps.

Comment: I will need compare items, generate stats based on queries, etc

Comment: This sounds like something that should not be performed at the whim of a user pushing a button

Comment: You say this could be a scheduled task with different workers?

Comment: Well PHP is a single-threaded language under **[MOST](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254)** circumstances so it can only go as fast as the thread allows it.

Comment: maybe using nodejs or rails is a good idea?

Comment: I don't have experience with either one. What are their benefits in this situation?

Comment: I don't think another language/framework is going to help here. What work are you wanting to do in those loops? Can it be pushed inside the database? I'm not familiar with Mongo, but that's how this would be solved in a traditional RDBMS. For example, if you are writing data, you'd try to use one `UPDATE` statement; and if you were doing something more complicated, maybe a stored procedure.

Comment: I have some experience with NodeJS and it is totally async.

Comment: @halfer, you say I should use database to keep temp data during process of script?

Comment: Making something `async` does not usually help a long running process because the user will simply think your app is broken and hit that "Process" button 10 more times.

Comment: @Leabdalla: I'm recommendng that you try to do loop operations as close to the data layer as possible. Please update your question with the work you are wanting to do in those loops - the problem is too abstract at the moment, imo.

Comment: I agree, every time you go for a `foreach()` loop you are potentially wasting PHP's single-threaded resources. If you can perform joins, calculations, functions, procedures on the DB level or within your actual SQL then you will be much better off performance-wise

Comment: Most MongoDB drivers don't perform work until the query is executed as it returns a Cursor. So the "find" just queues up the work, but doesn't fetch any data to the client.

Comment: Thanks guys, I agree.
One reference is the facebook segmentation tool: http://www.freshandnew.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/fb-step3-500x320.png
 Each filter you apply, it shows how many users you will reach. How could this compare billions of users in real time?

Comment: There are many aspects to managing "big data" such as data warehousing, HADOOP, and server-clustering

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I think FaceBook is using Objective-C for best performance anyways

Comment: If you want to stick with PHP then look into stuff like [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

Comment: I'll find technologies for big data. Thanks all!